# C# - How to change value of a progress bar in a secondary thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

In my program I import millions of records to a SQL Server database with the help of SqlBulkCopy class. Since this is a heavy lifting it takes quite some time. While the process goes on I want to show the progress in a progressbar control. To be notified for the rows copied I've done this:

```
.......
bulkCopy.NotifyAfter = 2000;
bulkCopy.SqlRowsCopied += new SqlRowsCopiedEventHandler(bulkCopy_SqlRowsCopied);
.......
```

Now in the bulkCopy_SqlRowsCopied method I want to change the value of the progress bar. But I think I need to make it on a seperate thread. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have one extension class, like

```
public static class ControlExtensions
{
    public static void Invoke(this Control control, Action action)
    {
        if (control.InvokeRequired) control.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(action), null);
        else action.Invoke();
    }
 }
```

Now when ever and where ever you want to update status of progress bar, you can do

```
progressBar.Invoke(() => { progressBar.PerformStep(); };
```

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You could execute your copy in a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and use `ReportProgress` to update your progressbar...
You can find an example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx.

The use of a `BackgroundWorker` for time-consuming operations is good because your UI (with the main thread) is free to be updated/refreshed, making user experience better.

Comment: Why does he need a BackGroundWorker? The Event that he has stated is raised at a variety of times, depending on the NotofyAfter property, whilst the BulkCopy processes the request.

Comment: @Lloyd: If his `BulkCopy` is executed in main thread, UI won't be updated if user tries to do something, just progressbar will. Using a `BackgroundWorker` makes UI free...

Answer (score 1):

For non-collection properties WPF will marshall the value on to the UI thread for you. So if you have a ViewModel with a progress property that raises the PropertyChanged event you can bind your ProgressBar to the ProgressBar.

For this to work, your ViewModel instance should not be a DependencyObject (but that is a bad idea for so many reasons). This way you can reference it from your background thread and set the Progress property.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Invoke()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.invoke.aspx) Method of the ProgressBar Control in your EventHandler "bulkCopy_SqlRowsCopied", make sure you set the [NotifyAfter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.sqlrowscopied.aspx) property of the SqlBulkCopy class to an amount that would reflect some form of percentage.

> Now in the bulkCopy_SqlRowsCopied method I want to change the value of the progress bar. But I think I need to make it on a seperate thread. How can I do this?

If you are using .Net 4.0 you could start your bulk copy in a Task, other versions you could use the ThreadPool, create your own thread

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(MyBulkCopyMethod);
```